# JS Impossible to change className

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class

I'm trying to update the class of first children of div#programmation

```
<div id="programmationEtat">
   <div class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
   <div class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
   <div class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
   ...
</div>
```

I tried that:

```
var children = document.getElementById("programmationEtat").children;
console.log(children);
children[0].className = 'active';
console.log(children);
```

First console log says:

> tab-pane ng-scope

Second says:

> active

But nothing changed and when I look at the HTML (chrome debugger) I still have

```
<div class="tab-pane ng-scope">
```

What am I doing wrong ?!
Thank you in advance !

**EDIT:** 
I found the problem:
I was using a dynamic directive on a scope that contained this div:

```
   app.directive('dynamic', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function (html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

And I have

```
$scope.programmation='...<div id="programmationEtat">
       <div class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
       <div class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
       <div class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
       ...
    </div>...'
```

HTML:

```
<div dynamic="programmation" id="programmationEtat">
    ... 
</div>
```

It looks like update with a document.getElementById(...) is impossible on something that is contained in $scope.programmation, have to update on $scope.programmation directly.

To solve my problem I used replace function ($scope.programmation.replace(...)) !

Comment: Your code works perfectly.

Comment: Then something else is making it wrong but I can't find what. Thank's for the edit @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut

Comment: My guess is that Angular controls the classes as opposed to native JS.

Comment: Which Javascript plugins and frameworks are you using?

Comment: If you are using only native javascript your code should work fine. I have updated it in online http://plnkr.co/edit/AWhaohBDQiBztpMAyP9P

Comment: @BenCodeZen Maybe the problem came from here. I'll dissect my code and try to find where the problem is. I give a solution later (I hope), thank's all.

Comment: Sorry for responding a bit late, I found my problem, look at the edit. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use ng-class:

```
<div id="programmationEtat">
   <div ng-class="className"class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
   <div class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
   <div class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
</div>

$scope.className = 'active';
```

OR:

```
<div id="programmationEtat">
   <div ng-class="{ 'active': activated }"class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
   <div class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
   <div class="tab-pane ng-scope">...</div>
</div>

$scope.activated = true;
```

Comment: Interesting alternative. How this works ? Is it possible to have a ng-class and a class ? (I found my problem, look at my edit, I don't know if it will works)